# How much should one bid to maximize the expected profit?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

I have this problem which I have been struggling with now for a while.

> "You bid on an object at a silent auction. You know that you can sell
>   it later for $100 and you estimate that the maximum bid from others is
>   uniform on [70,130]. (For convenience, you assume that it is
>   continuous, thus disregarding the possibility of two equal bids). How
>   much should you bid to maximize your expected profit, and what is the
>   maximum of the expected profit?"

My attempt to solve this goes like this.

Let the random variable $Y$ denote my profit after I sell the object, and let

$X$ be the random variable denoting the other peoples maximum bid.

We know from the text that $X$∽$unif[70,130]$ and we can therefore easily compute $X$'s pdf and expected value.

Now, my plan is to find a function $g$ such that $Y=g(X)$ and then calculate $E[Y]=E[g(X)]$ and later maximize. I tried to set $Y=100-X$ but that doesnt make any sense. I have no idea how to continue from here. I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction on this one.

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty clearly, your optimal bid should be between $70$ and $100$.  If you bid $x$ within this range, your chance of winning is $\frac{x-70}{60}$, and if you win, your resale profit is $100-x$.

So your expected value for bidding $x$ in the range $[70,100]$ is $\frac{(x-70)(100-x)}{60}$.

You should be able to maximize that expression with respect to $x$.